# Swift NWConnection for UDP -- handler not being called when connection refused by remote host, but is for other network errors

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to use NWConnection for network connection over UDP.  This mostly works fine.  However, the completion handler for the send method is not called when the connection is refused by the remote host, even though there is output in the console window.  This is not an issue for no route to host or host down errors.  I want to be able to handle connection refused errors.  How can I do this?

I'm setting up the connection as follows:

```swift
    func connect(){
        connection = NWConnection(host: host, port: port, using: .udp)
        
        connection!.stateUpdateHandler = { (newState) in
            switch (newState) {
            case .preparing:
                NSLog("Host \(self.host) Entered state: preparing")
            case .ready:
                NSLog("Host \(self.host) Entered state: ready")
            case .setup:
                NSLog("Host \(self.host) Entered state: setup")
            case .cancelled:
                NSLog("Host \(self.host) Entered state: cancelled")
            case .waiting:
                NSLog("Host \(self.host) Entered state: waiting")
            case .failed:
                NSLog("Host \(self.host) Entered state: failed")
            default:
                NSLog("Host \(self.host) Entered an unknown state")
            }
        }
        
        connection!.viabilityUpdateHandler = { (isViable) in
            if (isViable) {
                NSLog("Host \(self.host) Connection is viable")
                let _ = self.register()
                let _ = self.receiveMessage(connection: self.connection!, repeated: true)
            } else {
                NSLog("Host \(self.host) Connection is not viable")
            }
        }
        
        connection!.betterPathUpdateHandler = { (betterPathAvailable) in
            if (betterPathAvailable) {
                NSLog("Host \(self.host) A better path is availble")
            } else {
                NSLog("Host \(self.host) No better path is available")
            }
        }
        
        connection!.start(queue: .global())
    }
```

Then, my send method looks like this:

```swift
    func send(_ payload: Data) {
        connection!.send(content: payload, completion: .contentProcessed({ [self] sendError in
            if let error = sendError {
                NSLog("Unable to process and send the data: \(error)")
                errorCmdHandler(error)
            } else {
                NSLog("Data has been sent")
            }
            
        }))
    }
```

The error condition is being triggered by no route to host and host is down errors, but *not* connection refused errors.  This can be seen in the following excerpts from the console:

```
2023-05-10 01:28:27.410350-0400 Mute and Send[77993:1162126] [connection] nw_write_request_report [C3] Send failed with error "Host is down"
2023-05-10 01:28:29.087137-0400 Mute and Send[77993:1162232] Unable to process and send the data: POSIXErrorCode(rawValue: 64): Host is down
2023-05-10 01:27:04.061031-0400 Mute and Send[77993:1160989] [connection] nw_socket_service_writes_block_invoke [C3:1] sendmsg(fd 7, 8 bytes) [65: No route to host]
2023-05-10 01:27:04.061147-0400 Mute and Send[77993:1160989] [] nw_flow_prepare_output_frames Failing the write requests [65: No route to host]
2023-05-10 01:27:04.061209-0400 Mute and Send[77993:1160989] [connection] nw_write_request_report [C3] Send failed with error "No route to host"
2023-05-10 01:27:04.061319-0400 Mute and Send[77993:1161213] Unable to process and send the data: POSIXErrorCode(rawValue: 65): No route to host
2023-05-10 01:33:14.058461-0400 Mute and Send[77993:1162394] [connection] nw_socket_get_input_frames [C1:1] recvmsg(fd 5, 9216 bytes) [61: Connection refused]
```

Since the error handling code in my send completion is being triggered, I can easily handle the other two network errors, but not connection refused.  How can I pass a closure to be called in the event of a connection refused error?